# Occasional stuck splash screen (win 7 embedded)

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an application that restores windows on startup but this results in a potential flicker as each window is created and positioned.

To get around this I have the splash screen (stretched to the full size of the screen) set to "StayOnTop" and close it after the OnShow event using a TTask. The problem is that occasionally the splash screen gets stuck. If you click where buttons should be they redraw and show correctly. 
I have tried to "invalidate" all WinControls but this problem still shows up. 
I have never seen the problem in the debugger.

Are there any other tricks anyone can suggest to forcing a full repaint of the screen?

Here is my code to close the splash - This is in the OnShow of the main form.

```
aTask := TTask.Create(procedure()
  begin
    Sleep(800);
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure()
      begin
        fSplash.Close;
        FreeAndNil(fSplash);
        DoInvalidate(self);
      end);
  end);
aTask.Start;
```

Here is my attempt to invalidate everything...

```
Procedure DoInvalidate( aWinControl: TWInControl );
var
  i: Integer;
  ctrl: TControl;
begin
  for i:= 0 to aWinControl.Controlcount-1 do
  begin
    ctrl:= aWinControl.Controls[i];
    if ctrl Is TWinControl then
      DoInvalidate( TWincontrol( ctrl ));
  end;
  aWinControl.Invalidate;
end;
```

Martin

Comment: Did you try to use simple TTimer instead the TTask? Did you try to comment FreeAndNil(fSplash) and check if this changes anything?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recursively invalidate everything, just invalidating the Form itself is sufficient.

If you upgrade to 10.2 Tokyo, you can now use `TThread.ForceQueue()` instead of `TThread.Synchronize()` in a `TTask`:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure
    begin
      FreeAndNil(fSplash);
      Application.MainForm.Invalidate;
    end
  );
end;
```

If you stick with `TTask`, you should at least use `TThread.Queue()` instead:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Create(procedure
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
      begin
        FreeAndNil(fSplash);
        Application.MainForm.Invalidate;
      end;
    end
  ).Start;
end;
```

Or, you could just use a short `TTimer`, like zdzichs suggested:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  FreeAndNil(fSplash);
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Or, you could assign an `OnClose` event handler to the splash form to invalidate the MainForm, and then `PostMessage()` a `WM_CLOSE` message to the splash form:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fSplash := TSplashForm.Create(nil);
  fSplash.OnClose := SplashClosed;
  fSplash.Show;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fSplash <> nil then
    PostMessage(fSplash.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.SplashClosed(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  fSplash := nil;
  Action := caFree;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Or, use the `OnDestroy` event instead:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fSplash := TSplashForm.Create(nil);
  fSplash.OnDestroy := SplashDestroyed;
  fSplash.Show;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fSplash <> nil then
    fSplash.Release; // <-- delayed free
end;

procedure TMainForm.SplashDestroyed(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fSplash := nil;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: ForceQueue is a new one to me. I will look that up but I have not made the move to Tokyo because of the bugs doing mobile development. I am not sure why Queue should be any different in this case but worth a try.

Comment: The Timer idea might be the best one although less elegant code wise.